Unable to remove backslash from json response in azure APIM policy
While adding a inbound and backend policy in Azure APIM i am facing issue with json parsing
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-variable name="originalRequestBody" value="@{
            return context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true);
        }" />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://api-qa.integrator.bnksvc.com/berpContractService/api/v1/" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="backendResponse">
            <set-url>@("https://xxx-xx.xxx.xxx.com/berpContractService/api/v1/processcontracts")</set-url>
            <set-method>POST</set-method>
            <set-body>@{
                var originalBody = (JObject)context.Variables["originalRequestBody"];
                string jsonString = originalBody.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
                jsonString = jsonString.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
                return jsonString;
            }</set-body>
        </send-request>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <return-response response-variable-name="backendResponse" />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

{\"requestid\":\"0d8db8ec-f878-4954-a07a-2d086qqq\",\"contract\":\"avasacs\"}


My json from inbound body is getting converted  and  backshlash is added.
I want to remove these backslashes before sending json to backend


I believe your policy is correct and it works perfectly fine. If you will see the actual value of originalRequestBody variable, it doesn't contain any backslash here.

Thanks for reply @Ikhtesam.  You are right it correctly generate the json in Inbound. But when it is accessed in backend policy it adds backslash.
@{
var originalBody = (JObject)context.Variables["originalRequestBody"];
string jsonString = originalBody.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
jsonString = jsonString.Replace(@"", string.Empty);
return jsonString;
}

While sending it to backend, its adding the slashes in the expression but the value doesn't contain any backslashes, for example the output we are getting using this policy

output coming from set-body policy which doesn't contain any backslashes, I have used your policy

Try to move the set-header block to set the Content-Type within the backend section. This ensures that the content type is set correctly for the backend request.
<backend>
    <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="backendResponse">
        <set-url>@("https://xxx-xx.xxx.xxx.com/berpContractService/api/v1/processcontracts")</set-url>
        <set-method>POST</set-method>
        <set-body>@{
            var originalBody = (JObject)context.Variables["originalRequestBody"];
            string jsonString = originalBody.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
            jsonString = jsonString.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
            return jsonString;
        }</set-body>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
    </send-request>
</backend>


Thanks for the reply @TempoClick.
Got below error while adding content-type in backend:
Error in element 'send-request' on line 12, column 10: The element 'send-request' has invalid child element 'set-header'. List of possible elements expected: 'authentication-certificate, authentication-token, authentication-token-store, authentication-managed-identity, proxy'.

It worked, I had to add this after set-method . after set-body it gave error
POST

application/json

